# how do you subset data frame based on several conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to subset this data frame called:

```
df

Server     Model    Slot  
  server1    Cisco     1        
  server1    Cisco     2         
  server1    Cisco     3        
  server1    Cisco     4         
  server1    Cisco     8        
  server1    Cisco   Chasis
  server1    Cisco   Chasis
  server2    IBM     Slot 5        
  server2    IBM     Slot 8         
  server2    IBM     Slot 9 
  server3    Micr    Slot 22       
  server3    Micr    Slot 18        
  server3    Micr    Slot 1
  server3    Micr    Chasis 1
```

subset df will include Slot values less and equal to 12 or Slot values include "Slot" text in them.

Final data frame need to look like this:

```
Server     Model    Slot  
  server1    Cisco     1        
  server1    Cisco     2         
  server1    Cisco     3        
  server1    Cisco     4         
  server1    Cisco     8        
  server2    IBM     Slot 5        
  server2    IBM     Slot 8         
  server2    IBM     Slot 9 
  server3    Micr    Slot 22       
  server3    Micr    Slot 18        
  server3    Micr    Slot 1
```

I tried this:

```
df[df['Slot']=<12 || df['Slot].str.contains("Slot")]
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar, I just updated my question.

Comment: You don't use `&&` and `||` inside filtering expressions in pandas, you use `&` and `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have strings in the column `"Slot"`:

```py
mask = df["Slot"].str.contains(r"^(?:\d|1[0-2])$|Slot")
print(df[mask])
```

Prints:

```
     Server  Model     Slot
0   server1  Cisco        1
1   server1  Cisco        2
2   server1  Cisco        3
3   server1  Cisco        4
4   server1  Cisco        8
7   server2    IBM   Slot 5
8   server2    IBM   Slot 8
9   server2    IBM   Slot 9
10  server3   Micr  Slot 22
11  server3   Micr  Slot 18
12  server3   Micr   Slot 1
```

---

If you have mix of numbers/strings, convert all to strings:

```py
mask = df["Slot"].astype(str).str.contains(r"^(?:\d|1[0-2])$|Slot")
print(df[mask])
```

Comment: Does pandas allow a mix of datatypes in a column?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you can do for example `df.at[0, "Slot"] = 1; df.at[1, "Slot"] = "2"`

Comment: @AndrejKesely how do you make this mask to be data frame?

Comment: @user1471980 Do you mean how do you create a dataframe from the mask? you can do `df_new = df[mask]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely when I do df_new, I get boolean values, true false etc

Comment: @user1471980 That sounds like you did `df_new = mask`

Comment: @user1471980 `mask` is boolean Series. `df_new = df[mask]` (note the `df[mask]`) returns a dataframe.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ok, this works one quick question. Need to exclude records that "Sub" in df["Slot"]. Some records have subSlot stuff like this

Comment: @user1471980 You can change the mask to `mask = df["Slot"].str.contains(r"^(?:\d|1[0-2])$|\bSlot")` (note the `\b` in front of `Slot`)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem creating a mask using apply will work:

```
threshold =12
mask = df['Slot'].apply(lambda x: int(x) <= threshold if x.isdigit() else 'slot' in x.lower())
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
     Server  Model     Slot
0   server1  Cisco        1
1   server1  Cisco        2
2   server1  Cisco        3
3   server1  Cisco        4
4   server1  Cisco        8
7   server2    IBM   Slot 5
8   server2    IBM   Slot 8
9   server2    IBM   Slot 9
10  server3   Micr  Slot 22
11  server3   Micr  Slot 18
12  server3   Micr   Slot 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think general code is like this.

```
cond1 = pd.to_numeric(df['Slot'], errors='coerce').le(12)
cond2 = df['Slot'].str.contains('Slot')
df[cond1 | cond2]
```